# Using built-in checkstyle configuraiton from command line

Tags: java, git-bash, checkstyle

I'm new to Java programming and had thought that it would be beneficial for me to instill good style habits from the beginning. Upon downloading the [`checkstyle-7.6.1-all.jar` file](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/checkstyle/checkstyle/7.6.1/checkstyle-7.6.1-all.jar), I tried to run the following from the Bash command line:

```
java -jar checkstyle-7.6.1-all.jar -c /google_checks.xml TimeConvert.java
```

and was presented with the message:

```
Could not find config XML file 'C:/Program Files/Git/google_checks.xml'.
```

What I had ran from the command line was what was recommended by the Checkstyle website.

From what I've gathered so far, it seems that the XML file containing the google style specifications should be contained within the `.jar` file I downloaded.
My guess is that I need to specify more precisely the location of the XML file, but I'm not sure.

When I search the internet for answers, a lot of the information I find is for advanced users looking to write a custom checkstyle configuration.
Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git bash, '`/`' refers to the installation folder of Git.

You need to get the full path of that [`google_checks.xml` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) mentioned in the [checkstyle "Download and Run" section](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html#Download_and_Run):

```
/c/path/to/google_checks.xml
```

Comment: So my only option is to to download the XML file, place it somewhere and then specify this location when I'm trying to run checkstyle?

Comment: @BrandonSweeting That is the idea, yes.